# C++ Program to detect if Parenthesis, Brackets and Braces are Balanced - Need to Output Caret Under Errors

Tags: c++

I need to write a program that uses a stack to verify if a string expression is balanced, in regards to the parenthesis, brackets, and curly braces contained in it. The string's are to be inputted by the user, and all errors (i.e. mismatched parenthesis, brackets, and curly braces) need to be pointed out by a caret on the next line, directly under it, like this:

*(a bit hard to show here...)*

(()

^

In my "balanced" function, I am taking the current index of the loop, and assigning it to either "unmatchedRightPosition" or "unmatchedLeftPosition," whichever one is needed, at the time. I think that a lot of my program works already, but I'm having problems with placing the carets under the errors. My professor suggested that I may choose to use a stack class that holds structs, where each struct contains both a char and the char's position, but I am a bit puzzled by that.

Thanks for looking

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct Stack{
    static const unsigned MAX_SIZE = 5;
    char data[ MAX_SIZE ];
    unsigned size;
};

struct Stack2{

 unsigned unmatchedLeftPos, unmatchedRightPos;

};

void initialize( Stack & stack );
void show( const Stack & stack );
unsigned getSize( const Stack & stack );
void push( Stack & stack, char c );
char pop( Stack & stack );
char top( const Stack & stack );
bool die( const string & msg );
bool balanced (unsigned & unmatchedLeftPos, unsigned & unmatchedRightPos, const string & expr);

int main(){


    Stack2 s2;

    cout << "\nPlease enter your expression - enter a blank line to quit. \n";

    for(;;){

        string line;
        getline(cin, line);


        if( line.size() == 0 )  break;

            if (balanced(s2.unmatchedLeftPos, s2.unmatchedRightPos, line) == 1){

                cout << "OK\n";

            }

            else if (balanced(s2.unmatchedLeftPos, s2.unmatchedRightPos, line) == 0){

            cout << string(s2.unmatchedLeftPos, ' ') << '^';
            cout << string(s2.unmatchedRightPos, ' ') << '^';

            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

void initialize( Stack & stack ){
    stack.size = 0;
}

void show( const Stack & stack ){
    cout <<"[" << stack.size <<"]:";
    for(  unsigned i = 0;  i < stack.size;  i++  )
        cout <<stack.data[i];
    cout <<endl;
} // show

unsigned getSize( const Stack & stack ) {return stack.size;}

void push( Stack & stack, char c ){
    if( stack.size == Stack::MAX_SIZE )  die( "push: overflow" );
    stack.data[stack.size++] = c;
} // push

char pop( Stack & stack ){
    if( stack.size == 0 )  die( "pop: underflow" );
    return stack.data[--stack.size];
} // pop

char top( const Stack & stack ){
    if( stack.size == 0 )  die( "top: underflow" );
    return stack.data[stack.size-1];
} // pop

bool die( const string & msg ){
    cerr <<endl <<"Fatal error: " << msg <<endl;
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

bool balanced (unsigned & unmatchedLeftPos, unsigned & unmatchedRightPos, const string & expr){

    Stack s;
    initialize(s);

    unsigned i;

    for (i = 0; i < expr.size(); i++){

        char c = expr[i];

        if( expr.size() == Stack::MAX_SIZE)  {
                die( "push: overflow" );
            }

        if (c == '(')
        {
            push(s, c);
        }

        else if (c == '['){
            push(s, c);
        }

        else if (c == '{'){
            push(s, c);
        }

        if (s.size == 0 && (c == ')' || c == ']' || c == '}'))

        {
            unmatchedRightPos = i;
            return false;
        }

        else if (c == ')' && top(s) == '('){
            pop(s);
        }

        else if (c == ']' && top(s) == '['){
            pop(s);
        }

        else if (c == '}' && top(s) == '{'){
            pop(s);
        }

    }

    if (s.size == 0){

        return true;
    }

    else if (top(s) == '(' || top(s) == '[' || top(s) == '{'){

        unmatchedLeftPos = i;
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I believe your professor is recommending a stack that will hold errors. Each error will be held in a struct, with a variable for the position in the string where it occurred and probably a char to say what character is incorrect. To display the carets, create a string with spaces, and insert a ^ for every position that is popped off the stack.

Answer (score 2):

You are currently using stack, with an array of characters:

```
char data[ MAX_SIZE ];
```

Instead, you would go for a struct, that holds both character and position in the input string

```
struct info {
    char data;
    int pos;
};

info data[ MAX_SIZE ];
```

So at the end, you just check your stack, and in addition to invalid characters, you also have the position in the input string.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can move your main to the bottom to avoid forward function declarations. You also don't need to use another stack for the errors (actually I think it's easier if you don't). You just need to hold both the bracket and its position on a single stack, i.e.

```
struct Item
{
    char bracket;
    size_t position;
}

std::stack<Item> st;
```

As well as either an array or, better a string initialized to the same length as the input string with all spaces which you change to `'^'` upon encountering an error, i.e.

```
std::string errorString(input.size(), ' ');

if ( /* brackets don't match */ )
{
    errorString[st.top().position] = '^';
}
```

In case you cannot use STL stack, you need to modify your own to hold `Item` objects instead of char (i.e. Item data[ MAX_SIZE ];). Your code looks very much like C thought and it would be better if you made use of `std::string` and `std::stack` instead.

Comment: `You don't need to declare your methods in advance in C++. That's a C thing.` -- Not true. The code won't compile without forward declarations if the definitions are after main (which is what @OP has).. It's the same in both C and C++.

Comment: Ah right, I didn't notice his main is up there. Fixed.